# apollo-ios How to cache data on disk?

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo-ios

I need cache my data on disk for offline view, I found ApolloSQLite in the apollo-ios source, but I can't find any documents of ApolloSQLite(I also tried Google search).

**Environment:**

```
Xcode 10.1
macOS 10.14.3
CocoaPods 1.5.3

Apollo (0.9.5)
SQLite.swift (0.11.5)
```

Too many errors coming after `pod install`:

```
pod 'Apollo'
pod 'Apollo/SQLite'
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I use `CocoaPods 1.5.3`, missing the source `Apollo/Core` after `pod install`, it causes the errors. I've fixed it by upgrade CocoaPods to 1.6.0.

BTW, the original question is **how to use ApolloSQLite?** Because I've not found any documents for ApolloSQLite. After too many search & query, I list my steps as below for other people for help:

1. use CocoaPods for manage the libs:

> ```
> pod 'Apollo'
> pod 'Apollo/SQLite'
> ```

2. need a file path to save the sqlite file which use for cache data. Paste my codes for refer:

   ```
   func temporarySQLiteFileURL() -> URL {
       let applicationSupportPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.applicationSupportDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
       let dbPath = applicationSupportPath + "/com.[special name].cache"

       if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dbPath) {
           try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dbPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
       }

       let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: dbPath)
       return url.appendingPathComponent("db.sqlite3")
   }
   ```
3. configure the ApolloClient:

   ```
       let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
       configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10

       let url = URL(string: self.graphQLApiAddress!)!
       let networkTransport = HTTPNetworkTransport(url: url, configuration: configuration)

       let cache = try? SQLiteNormalizedCache(fileURL: temporarySQLiteFileURL())
       let store = ApolloStore(cache: cache ?? InMemoryNormalizedCache())
       self.apolloClient = ApolloClient(networkTransport: networkTransport, store: store)
   ```

Comment: Perfect guide for getting you started with apollo. Shame there is little information about getting started within the docs